# python get ipv4 from default interface

Tags: python, ipv4

I'm looking for code but can't find what I'm looking for exactly.

I want to obtain the ipv4 of all the interfaces of the pc.

any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not guaranteed to work, depends on system configuration. But you can try this for the *default* interface:

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())) # IP in string, e.g. '192.168.1.123'
```

If you want to enumerate *all* interfaces, likely that would be system dependent (e.g. Windows vs Linux), see for example [here](https://gist.github.com/pklaus/289646) for a Python 2 code, or you can simply parse the output from system command `ifconfig`.